# Array with the names of my Dataframes in Pandas

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe

I wanna get the array with the names of my Datafremes:

```
#Dataframes have already been created

df1.name = 'df1'
df2.name = 'df2'
df3.name = 'df3'

dataframes = df1, df2, df3

array_names_of_dfs = [[] for a in dataframes ]
array_names_of_dfs = [[array_names_of_dfs.append([i.name]) for i in dataframes]
```

And I would like to get such array:

```
[[df1], [df2], [df3]]
```

But now the output is:

```
[None, None, None]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: DataFrame's  index and column has name attribute but not the DataFrame itself I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two lines in your code snippet are wrong (you are appending within a list comprehension). Perhaps this is what you are interested in?

```py
import pandas as pd

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(range(3), columns=['a']) for _ in range(3)]
array_names_of_dfs = [f'df_{n}' for n in range(3)]

array_names_of_dfs
```